# Android application suddenly crashes

Tags: android, xml, crash

I was working on my application over 2 weeks, and suddenly it crashes everytime I hit the start button.
It's important to mention that its crashes on my main phone (note 3) and on my developer phone(100$ phone) it works. The log says something about an XML file (it's a popup window).

**Here is the log:**

```
05-14 22:18:40.604  28373-28373/? E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 23289136-byte allocation.
05-14 22:18:40.614  28373-28373/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: think.example.com.think, PID: 28373
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{think.example.com.think/think.example.com.think.FirstQuestion}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at think.example.com.think.FirstQuestion.onCreate(FirstQuestion.java:70)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at think.example.com.think.FirstQuestion.onCreate(FirstQuestion.java:70)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:872)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3054)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3694)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3624)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:474)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:236)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at think.example.com.think.FirstQuestion.onCreate(FirstQuestion.java:70)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**This is the xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/cluebackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:minHeight="400dp"
    >

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp "
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:background="@drawable/roundexit"

        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:onClick="exitPopup"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:paddingTop="55dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:paddingEnd="50dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="21dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:background="@drawable/coin"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="100"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/clueScore" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/clue"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="It will cost you 50 coins to get the clue"
            android:textSize="27dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:textColor="#fffefdff"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Get clue"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/stylepressed"
        android:onClick="getClue" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I also want to mention that if I delete the rows that relate to this XML on my java 'on create' method, it works.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_question);

        write = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.writeAnswer);
        gameScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gameScore);

        //SET POPUP MENU
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) FirstQuestion.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, null);

        init();
        popupInit();
        //END OF POPUP

        //CLUE POPUP
        clueScore = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.clueScore); 
        clue = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.clue);

        //GET SCORE getting preferences
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("Score", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int savedScore = prefs.getInt("key", 100); //0 is the default value**

        gameScore.setText(Integer.toString(savedScore));
        clueScore.setText(gameScore.getText().toString());
        //GET SCORE



    }
```

Comment: cluebackground this is causing out of memory is it a image if yes looks like something is wrong with it

Comment: @apk You are absolutely right. Can I ask how did you notice that this is the problem? because I couldn't find it through the log report.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have this message in your `LogCat` output:

```
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
```

and an `OutOfMemoryError`

```
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:872)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3054)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
```

some of the images referenced into your layout has a big size and need a lot of memory to be displayed.

Comment: @Yakirbu you are welcome, did you realize that you have big size images?

Comment: Yes I did, I had to resize each background since I saved them in a very high resolution.